# XCode 15 - Getting WatchKit Extension Error while Project try to run in real device

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, xcode15, rosetta

Facing a error when switch project Xcode 14 to Xcode 15 in M1 Mac.
In simulator it is working fine but when try to real device getting error.

[Getting error on M1 Mac while try to run in real device]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YBBD.png)

Change **EXCLUDED_ARCHS** to **arm64**.
Add **VALID_ARCHS** in Add User-Defind Setting.
Also try all solution of below link.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon/

[Add and remove other linker flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpoWW.png)

Comment: That framework was only made for simulator

Comment: This framework is working on the device using XCode 14, But When I switch XCode 14 to 15 I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Manual framework then follow the below steps.

1. Remove files from the project and add again while adding a file select a target. Please check attached image.
   [Select target Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSZEC.png)
2. Remove **Other Linker Flag** and **Header Search Path** from the Build Setting of **WatchKit Extension**.
   (WatchKit Extension Target -> Build Setting -> Other Linker Flag).

   (WatchKit Extension Target -> Build Setting -> Header Search Path).
3. Clean Project
4. Build the project